# Verify directory write privileges

Tags: python, posix

I am writing a program in Python 2.7 that retrieves remote files and dumps them in a directory that can be specified by the user. Currently, in order to verify that the program can in fact write to that directory, I do the following (assuming that dumpdir is a string containing the name of the directory to check):

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dumpdir+'/.mwcrawler')
    os.rmdir(dumpdir+'/.mwcrawler')
except:
    logging.error('Could not open %s for writing, using default', dumpdir)
```

But this feels even more hackish than my usual code. What's the correct way to go about this? Maybe some sort of assertion on privileges?

Comment: Well, for one thing, use `os.path.join` instead of string manipulation. For another, unless you're absolutely sure nobody can ever have a file named `.mwcrawler`, you probably want something out of the `tempfile` module. Also, you probably want to do `except Exception as e:` and log the exception, because as it stands you can't tell the difference between an actual OS error or, e.g., a pathname with an invalid character or non-encodable Unicode or whatever. Finally, "Could not open… for reading" is a weird error to print for a write failure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `os.path.join`, that will help in some other places in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission—you have to handle errors in writing each file anyway, so why check in advance?

But, when you have a user interface—even a command-line interface, where you may read a prefs file long before you get to any writing—it's often much more convenient to the user to return errors as soon as possible. As long as that's the only reason you're doing this check, there's nothing wrong with it.

However, there are many little ways you could improve the *way* you do the check.

First, you should almost never just use `except:` without specifying anything. Besides the fact that this catches different things in different versions of Python (and therefore also confuses human readers used to other versions), it means you have no way of distinguishing between not writable, a bad Unicode character, or even a typo in the code.

Plus, your error message says "not readable" if it can't write, which is pretty odd.

Second, unless you're sure nobody will ever have a file named `.mwcrawler` (e.g., because you refuse to transfer files starting with `'.'` or something), using any fixed name is just asking for trouble. A better solution is to use, e.g., `tempfile.mkdtemp`.

Also, you should avoid using string manipulation for paths if you want to be portable. That's what `os.path` (and higher-level utilities) are for—so you don't have to learn or think about Windows, zOS, etc.

Putting it all together:

```
try:
    d = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='.mwcrawler', dir=dumpdir)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Could not open %s for reading (%s), using default', dumpdir, e)
else:
    os.rmdir(d)
```

Comment: _Plus, your error message says "not readable" if it can't write, which is pretty odd._

Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access) describes the usage of `os.access`, a method specifically created for your needs.

It also explains a better way of approaching rights checking.

As also rightfully mentioned in comments, `os.access` will have issues in a few specific cases, so just to be totally sure, "hit-n-run" approach is actually better, try writing, catch exception, see what happened - go from there.

Comment: I don't think `os.access` is actually what you want here. There are many reasons why you might not be able to create files under a directory besides it not having `X_OK` permission. For example, if you have an SMB share that doesn't allow you to create files, it will usually return `True` for `os.access(path, os.X_OK)`. But I think the OP still wants to get an error in that case.

Comment: Who says anything about `X_OK`? Testing for `W_OK` can be one option, another one could be (in the same link described) approach of opening a file descriptor in `write` more and catching the exceptions. Only that catching each and every exception in that case is not a very good idea. Specifically catching `IOError` and verifying `if e.errno == errno.EACCES:` actually makes sure you ran into permission issue.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter _what_ you check for with `access`—there is no right answer. No matter what you pass, `access` will succeed in cases where actually attempting to create files will fail (e.g., with many SMB shares). There's even a big "Note:" about that in the doc page you linked. `access` is almost never what you want.

Comment: Good point. Networked locations will indeed have issues. Haven't thought about that.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know there's a function that purports to do this (even if it has some edge cases).